# Display the users location on a Mapkit with CLLocationManager

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I am using mapkit to display my map, I have also created an overlay. Now I am tracking the user using CLLocationManager and outputting that to the consol for testing. I hope someone knows or has a tutorial/example of how to place a dot or annotation where the users location is based on the lat lon results.. This is what I am doing at the moment..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Initialize the TileOverlay with tiles in the application's bundle's resource directory.
    // Any valid tiled image directory structure in there will do.
    NSString *tileDirectory = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Tiles"];
    TileOverlay *overlay = [[TileOverlay alloc] initWithTileDirectory:tileDirectory];
    [map addOverlay:overlay];

    // zoom in by a factor of two from the rect that contains the bounds
    // because MapKit always backs up to get to an integral zoom level so
    // we need to go in one so that we don't end up backed out beyond the
    // range of the TileOverlay.
    MKMapRect visibleRect = [map mapRectThatFits:overlay.boundingMapRect];
    visibleRect.size.width /= 2;
    visibleRect.size.height /= 2;
    visibleRect.origin.x += visibleRect.size.width / 2;
    visibleRect.origin.y += visibleRect.size.height / 2;
    map.visibleMapRect = visibleRect;

//    map.showsUserLocation = YES;
    //location tracking
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    [overlay release]; // map is now keeping track of overlay
}

//OverLays Topographical map
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    TileOverlayView *view = [[TileOverlayView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
    view.tileAlpha = 0.6;
    return [view autorelease];
}

//Tracks Users location and Prints out the Lat and Lon
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
   didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
          fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D here =  newLocation.coordinate;
    NSLog(@"%f  %f ", here.latitude, here.longitude);
}

//Call [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation] as some point
```

Comment: you can add map.showsUserLocation = YES;

Comment: oh right... I thought that was a map kit thing.. I'm going to try it now and see if it updates my location and tracks me.. will let you know how I go. :)

Comment: just tested out, ran up and down the road!!! perfect!! well had about a 5-10 meter inaccuracy at times but thats mint for what I'm doing.. wow cool! time to read this tutorial wanna find out more cool things I can try out :)